# C# Calendar - Switching CalendarItems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have Calendar control and button for setting up actual date.

Using function `SetToday()` I can set `SelectedDate` property, but I don't know how to set `CalendarItem` (month tab). The following 2 images explain my problem.

[img1 - another date clicked](http://postimg.org/image/g4fgfikit/) 
[img2 - Set Today button clicked](http://postimg.org/image/9n6irlinv/)

```
partial void SetToday_Execute()
{
    var cal = this.FindControl("Calendar1");
    cal.ControlAvailable += (object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var c = (System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)e.Control;
            c.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;                    
        };
}
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What control are you using to try and achieve this? The 'out of the box' datepicker? If it's not, it might be worth letting us know which one so we can look to be more helpful.

Comment: I'm using Calendar class - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I didn't read class documentation attentively. I forgot to set `DisplayDate` property. The function `SetToday()` now looks like this :

```
partial void SetToday_Execute()
{
    var cal = this.FindControl("Calendar1");
    cal.ControlAvailable += (object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var c = (System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)e.Control;
            c.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
            c.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now;
        };
}
```